# EF6 Migrations Precision in MetadataType

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, metadatatype

I'm trying to set Precision through MetadataType in EF6 Code First Migrations. If I set the attribute directly on the property in the class, it works correctly, but not if it's in the MetadataType class.

Is there anything I can do to get this to work (besides decorating them directly in the class)?

The [Precision solution](https://gist.github.com/mombrea/f7da81aba2d8d62e6929) is originally in C#.

I'd be happy to accept an answer in C#...I'll convert it.

Use case: The original class is not in my code / control.

**Test Console App**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Module Module1

    Friend MyAppSettings As New AppSettings
    Friend SqlConnect As String = String.Empty

    Sub Main()
        With New SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder() With {
            .DataSource = Path.Combine(MyAppSettings.SqlServer, MyAppSettings.SqlInstance),
            .InitialCatalog = MyAppSettings.SqlDatabase,
            .IntegratedSecurity = True, .PersistSecurityInfo = True,
            .MultipleActiveResultSets = True}

            SqlConnect = .ConnectionString
        End With

        With New MyEntities(SqlConnect)
            Try
                .Database.Initialize(True)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
            Finally
                .Dispose()
            End Try
        End With
    End Sub

End Module

<MetadataType(GetType(TestMetaData))>
Partial Public Class Test
    <Key>
    Public Property ID As Int64 = 0

    Public Property Description As String = String.Empty

    ' ** Precision works with Migrations when applied directly here **
    '<Precision(12, 6)>
    Public Property Measurement As Decimal?
End Class

Public Class TestMetaData
    <Column(TypeName:="varchar"), StringLength(100)>
    Public Property Description As String = String.Empty

    ' ** Precision FAILS with Migrations when applied through MetadataType **
    <Precision(15, 6)>
    Public Property Measurement As Decimal?
End Class

Public Class MyEntities
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        Database.SetInitializer(New MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion(Of MyEntities, Migrations.Configuration)(True))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ConnectionString As String)
        MyBase.New(ConnectionString)
        Database.SetInitializer(New MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion(Of MyEntities, Migrations.Configuration)(True))
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        Precision.ConfigureModelBuilder(ModelBuilder)
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Property TestData() As DbSet(Of Test)
End Class

<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple:=False)>
Public Class Precision
    Inherits Attribute

    Public Property Precision() As Byte
    Public Property Scale() As Byte

    Public Sub New(Precision As Byte, Scale As Byte)
        Me.Precision = Precision
        Me.Scale = Scale
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub ConfigureModelBuilder(ByRef ModelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        With ModelBuilder.Properties.Where(Function(x) x.GetCustomAttributes(False).OfType(Of Precision).Any)
            .Configure(Function(c) c.HasPrecision(c.ClrPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(False).OfType(Of Precision).First.Precision,
                                                  c.ClrPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(False).OfType(Of Precision).First.Scale))
        End With
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Migrations Code**

```
Imports System.Data.Entity.Migrations

Namespace Migrations

    Friend NotInheritable Class Configuration
        Inherits DbMigrationsConfiguration(Of MyEntities)

        Public Sub New()
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = False
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = True
        End Sub
    End Class

    Partial Public Class BaseSchema
        Inherits DbMigration

        Public Overrides Sub Up()
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Tests",
                Function(c) New With
                    {
                        .Clever_EDI_ID = c.Long(nullable:=False, identity:=True),
                        .Description = c.String(maxLength:=100, unicode:=False),
                        .Measurement = c.Decimal(precision:=18, scale:=2)
                    }) _
                .PrimaryKey(Function(t) t.Clever_EDI_ID)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub Down()
            DropTable("dbo.Tests")
        End Sub
    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: I personally find fluent configuration to be much more intuitive than data annotations. And it handles the case when you have no access to the class.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have `Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)` in the code above where the precision is being done. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Well, I meant doing it for a specific type property, e.g. for your `Test` class. The way written, I don't think your code hits the `Test` class properties because you are checking for attributes defined for property of the class, not on property of `MetadataType` class associated with `Test` class.

Comment: @IvanStoev Please note that the annotation for `<Column(TypeName:="varchar"), StringLength(100)>` is also in the MetadataType class and Migrations picks that up perfectly, as seen in the generated BaseSchema class.

Comment: I see it, but it's handled by EF infrastructure, while your custom attribute is processed by your code. And you are checking the `ClrPropertyInfo` which does not have such attribute.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok so that's why this works when it's directly in the class. What can I add / change to get it to see Precision in the MetadataType class?

Comment: I'm not familiar with VB.NET, so can't provide you an example. The easiest I see is to implement custom convention by inheriting from `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PropertyAttributeConfigurationConvention<YourAttribute>` and apply your logic in `Apply` method, which is called for every property having such attribute. This is the class EF uses itself, so it considers metadata redirection.